# Prove: If a continuous function is monotonic in $(a, b) $ then it is monotonic in $[a, b] $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, continuity, monotone-functions

> If a continuous function is monotonic in $(a, b) $ then it is monotonic in $[a, b] $

I conjectured this theorem for this would solve many doubts I had in monotonicity of functions.  I can see this intuitively but can someone provide a bit of rigour?

For example,  this can be used to prove that $y=x^3$ is monotonic for $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: I need hint level 2

Comment: @IncludedExcluded I don't know how to rate hints.

Comment: okay give me another hint plz

Comment: @IncludedExcluded Assume that $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is continuous and that it is increasing on $(a,b)$. If $f$ wasn't increasing, we would have $f(a)>f(x)$ for some $x\in(a,b)$ or $f(x)>f(b)$ for some $x\in(a,b)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was going to offer $\tan x$ on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ as a counterexample. Your assumption is necessary.

Comment: I got it I got it thanks a million tons!!!!!